# Email failing from hosted website through Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I have Exchange 2010 (on SBS 2011 server).  I'm trying to email from our hosted website through our Exchange server to an external email address.  But I can't get it to work.  I can email from the website to an internal email (somebody@mydomain.com), but not an external email (somebodyelse@anotherdomain.com).
I have set up a connector to accept the emails sent from the hosted website's IP address, but still no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Lee

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup a relay connector and setup the IP that is going to be relaying mail (hosted website) to be allowed to relay through that connector.  Also make sure to set it to "Externally Secured" in the Authentication tab of the connector.

Follow this guide, easy enough: http://exchangeserverpro.com/how-to-configure-a-relay-connector-for-exchange-server-2010/